# C memory leak in linked list

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I am triying to make a linked list in c consisting on various nodes that follow this structure:

```
typedef struct sll_node
{
  char label[LABEL_SIZE];
  int value;
  struct sll_node* next;
}sll_node;
```

My output is the expected one for every test I run the code in, but when running under valgrind I am getting a memory leak error;

```
==8001== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8001==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8001==    by 0x4012B8: make_node (slist.c:53)
==8001==    by 0x401337: sll_add (slist.c:91)
==8001==    by 0x40108B: test_stress1 (sample-driver.c:188)
==8001==    by 0x401277: main (sample-driver.c:258)
```

I've checked all the code for adding new nodes to the list but I think that there are no errors there

```
sll_node *sll_add(sll_node *list, int value, const char *label)
{
  sll_node *NewNode = make_node(value, label);
  sll_node *ListNode = list;

  if(list == 0)
    return NewNode;

  while(ListNode->next != 0)
  {
    ListNode = ListNode->next;
  }

  ListNode->next = NewNode;

  return list;
}
```

So I think that the only errors left are in the function that removes the nodes from the list.

The function is supposed to search in all the nodes for the one with the value that should be erased and return a new beginning to the list if the head node is changed as a result of this operation in case it doesn't find the search value it should just return the list pointer:

```
sll_node *sll_remove(sll_node *list, int search_value)
{
  sll_node *IwillDeleteThis = list;
  sll_node *ThisIsBeforeWhatIWillDelete = 0;


  if(list == 0)
    return 0;

  if(list->value == search_value)
  {
    if(list->next)
    {
      sll_node *NewBeginning = list->next;
      free(list);
      return NewBeginning;
    }
    free(list);
    return 0;
  }


  while(IwillDeleteThis)
  {
    if(IwillDeleteThis->value == search_value)
    {
      ThisIsBeforeWhatIWillDelete->next = IwillDeleteThis->next;
      free(IwillDeleteThis);
      return list;
    }
    ThisIsBeforeWhatIWillDelete = IwillDeleteThis;
    IwillDeleteThis = IwillDeleteThis->next;
  }

  return list;
}
```

I think that there is a possible case that I am mising when it comes to evaluate the possibilities of the list I have to erase, but I don't know what case it's that.

Please It would be really helpful if you point me where I am wrong.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Just in case, this is the code I'm using to test my code:

```
#define VERBOSEx
void test_stress1(void)
{
  #define SIZE 4500
  sll_node *list = NULL;
  int i, count = 0;
  int *a = malloc(2 * SIZE * sizeof(int));
  char buf[LABEL_SIZE];

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    a[count++] = i + 1;
    sprintf(buf, "%08i", a[i]);
    list = sll_add(list, a[i], buf);  
  }
  #ifdef VERBOSE
  sll_dump(list);
  #endif

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    int r1 = RandomInt(0, 1);
    int r2 = RandomInt(1, count);
    a[count] = count + 1;
    count++;
    sprintf(buf, "%08i", count);

    if (r1)
      list = sll_insert_before(list, r2, count, buf);
    else
      sll_insert_after(list, r2, count, buf);

    #ifdef VERBOSE
    sll_dump(list);
    printf("%s %i", r1 ? "before" : "after", r2);
    #endif
  }
  #ifdef VERBOSE
  sll_dump(list);
  #endif

  /*PrintArray(a, count);*/
  Shuffle(a, count);
  /*PrintArray(a, count);*/

  for (i = 0; i < 2 * SIZE - 20; i++)
  {
    list = sll_remove(list, a[i]);
    #ifdef VERBOSE
    sll_dump(list);
    #endif
  }

  sll_dump(list);
  sll_destroy(list);

  free(a);
}
```

**EDIT2:**

And here is the code for destroying the list:

```
void sll_destroy(sll_node *list)
{
  sll_node *NodeToDelete = list;
  if(list == 0)
    return;  

  while(NodeToDelete)
  { 
    sll_node *DeleteNow = NodeToDelete;
    NodeToDelete = NodeToDelete->next;
    free(DeleteNow);
  }
}
```

**EDIT3:**
Some extra functions I use to add nodes to the list

```
sll_node *sll_insert_before(sll_node *list, int search_value, int value, const char *label)
{
  sll_node *NewNode = make_node(value, label);
  sll_node *NodeToChangePosWith = list;
  sll_node *PreviousNode = list;

  if(list->value != search_value)
  {
    while(NodeToChangePosWith != 0 &&
          NodeToChangePosWith->value != search_value)
    {
      PreviousNode = NodeToChangePosWith;
      NodeToChangePosWith = NodeToChangePosWith->next;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    NewNode->next = list;
    return NewNode;
  }

  if(NodeToChangePosWith == 0)
  {
    free(NewNode);
    return list;
  }
  PreviousNode->next = NewNode;
  NewNode->next = NodeToChangePosWith;
  if(PreviousNode == list)
  {
    return NewNode;
  }

  return list;
}


void sll_insert_after(sll_node *list, int search_value, int value, const char *label)
{
  sll_node *NewNode = make_node(value, label);
  sll_node *NodeToChangePosWith = list;

  while(NodeToChangePosWith->next != 0 &&
        NodeToChangePosWith->value != search_value)
  {
    NodeToChangePosWith = NodeToChangePosWith->next;
  }
  if(NodeToChangePosWith->next == 0 &&
     NodeToChangePosWith->value != search_value)
  {
    free(NewNode);
    return;
  }

  NewNode->next = NodeToChangePosWith->next;
  NodeToChangePosWith->next = NewNode;

}
```

Comment: The bug is probably elsewhere, e.g. if you *forgot* to call `sll_remove` or are calling it wrongly. You have to examine your *entire program*

Comment: I don't think that is in anywhere else, this ones are the only functions called when testing that valgrind says that fail.

Comment: I am going to add the functions I use to add nodes to the list, just in case

Comment: Don't expect us to study a lot of source code. You have to find out the leak!

Comment: I've been hours trying to find the leak, but I am unable to do it by myself, I am asking here because I really need help and I don't know where else to go.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use a debugger (`gdb`)?

Comment: what your sll_remove function returns ? is it node address which is removed ? i think you are returning dangling pointer `return list;`

Comment: AnKurTank sll_remove returns the pointer to the beginning of the list, that way I can tell the program that there is a new beginning if remove happens to remove the begginging of the list

Comment: oh i see, sorry my mistake.

Comment: I should probably have commented it

Comment: Some functions are missing, if it is possible for you why don't you attach full code as file attachment.

Comment: BTW, your linked list implementation looks a bit twisted and too complex. I would suggest you to study the source code of some free software using linked lists. It should inspire you.

Comment: I think you even allocate some memory in *main* function which is present here. Are you sure enough about deallocating it @blastxu.

Comment: The only thing main does is call the test function above, no other functions or allocations are made outside of this function

Comment: Valgrind suggests some line number did you look at those places. what is mkae_node does ?

Comment: one of most interesting functions is missing: make_node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in `sll_insert_before` when you insert before the second element of the list.  In this case, after the while loop, `PreviousNode` will be pointing at the first element, and `NodeToChangePosWith` will be pointing at the second element.  You insert `NewNode` between `PreviousNode` and `NodeToChangePosWith`, but then you have an unnecessary (and incorrect) test to see if `PreviousNode` is equal to `list` (which it is in this case), and you return `NewNode` as the new first element, which leaks the real first element.

Btw, the following code eliminates all of the special cases:

```
sll_node *sll_add(sll_node *list, int value, const char *label)
{
    sll_node *newNode = make_node(value, label);
    sll_node **nextPtr = &list;

    while(*nextPtr != 0)
    {
        nextPtr = &(*nextPtr)->next;
    }

    *nextPtr = newNode;

    return list;
}

sll_node *sll_remove(sll_node *list, int search_value)
{
    sll_node **nextPtr;
    sll_node *node;

    for(nextPtr = &list; (node = *nextPtr) != 0; nextPtr = &node->next)
    {
        if(node->value == search_value)
        {
            *nextPtr = node->next;
            free(node);
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

void sll_destroy(sll_node *list)
{
    while(list != 0)
    {
        sll_node *nodeToDelete = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(nodeToDelete);
    }
}

sll_node *sll_insert_before(sll_node *list, int search_value, int value, const char *label)
{
    sll_node **nextPtr;
    sll_node *node;

    for(nextPtr = &list; (node = *nextPtr) != 0; nextPtr = &node->next)
    {
        if(node->value == search_value)
        {
            sll_node *newNode = make_node(value, label);
            newNode->next = node;
            *nextPtr = newNode;
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

void sll_insert_after(sll_node *list, int search_value, int value, const char *label)
{
    while(list != 0)
    {
        if(list->value == search_value)
        {
          sll_node *newNode = make_node(value, label);
          newNode->next = list->next;
          list->next = newNode;
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you.
I can't believe it was that, I had looked so much my code that I lost track of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code that you copied here is too much; but for finding the bug I suggest you to do the following:

1- Use Valgrind's [Massif heap profiler](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

2- Use [Massif visualizer](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/sdk/massif-visualizer) to see where memory is allocated and freed (this tool visualizes the output of the last step.

3- Also in order to see what functions are called during you program execution I recommend you to use [Valgrind's Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) and [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to visualize it's output.

Comment: @Adarsh: It is a solution. The person who asked the question can use it to find his answer.

Comment: @Adarsh : Oh common. It is one of the solutions for finding the real answer. Don't be like that. Instead of arguing with me why don't you provide the answer if you know it?! My solution may help him to find the answer but your argument has no point at all.

Comment: I got the massif.out file but I don't know how to use the visualizer, I find the documentation confuse.
PS: Thank you for this tools :)

Comment: I never said that I know the answer @gst. I'm sorry if I hurt you. But I said what I felt on your solution.